# Posting string containing URL to server truncates everything after &

Tags: url, swift, encoding

I'm posting a string containing a URL (url encoded) to a server using swift and am formatting the url like the following.

```
url = "http://something.com/?blah=blah&stuff=stuff"
url = url.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

However everything after the & in the url is being cut off. So I'm hacking it like the following.

```
url = url!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&", withString:"FLAGABC123");
```

There has to be a better way to do this and any suggestions are appreciated.

The request is being posted using:

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: nsurl!, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 2.0)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let params = "path=(path)"
let http_body = params.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
request.HTTPBody = http_body
let session = auth.sessionWithAuth(email, password: "")
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler:{(dataObject, response, error) in
```

Comment: When is it being cut off.  The two lines you include will result in a string that is identical to the original, since none of the characters require percent escaping.  How are you posting it?

Comment: hist a gist showing how I'm posting : https://gist.github.com/captainchung/c343bc949536e6b8783e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all percentEscapes is for url encoding.  The ampersand is allowed in a url.  You are trying to pass a string with an & as a value in post data.  However, on the server side, the & is parsed to mean another key and value is starting.

What you want is then HTML encoding, not url encoding.  Swift doesn't have a builtin function to do this, but I suppose you could create your own.  In the case of the ampersand, you just need to replace it with &

```
url = url!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&", withString:"&amp;");
```